# Create a Partition Function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I have created a partition function but I am not able to apply it to a table. I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Here is my partition function:

```
     CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION StaticDateMonthPartition (int)
     AS RANGE left
     FOR VALUES     (   
                    20120301,
                    20120401,
                    20120501,
                    20120601,
                    20120701,
                    20120801,
                    20120901,
                    20121001,
                    20121101,
                    20121201,
                    20130101,
                    20130201
                    )
```

trying to apply to this table:

```
    IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[partition_OLAP_Fact_vvv]') AND type in (N'U'))
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[partition_OLAP_Fact_vvv]
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partition_OLAP_Fact_vvv]
    (
        FFFFactvvvId            bigint,
        CORStaticDateId         int,
        CORVersionvvvId         bigint,
        vvvCount                tinyint,
        UPB                     decimal(18, 2)
    ) ON  CORStaticDateMonthPartition ([CORStaticDateId])
```

But when I try to execute the table script I get this error:

```
    Invalid partition scheme 'CORStaticDateMonthPartition' specified
```

Please Help.

---

Reposting my code with steps

[Pinal's](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/) tutoral is great! Here's a quick summary

1. Add file groups for each of your partitions

   ```
   Alter Database [database]   Add FileGroup partition_201207
   ```
2. Create Partition Function

   ```
   CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION Partition_Range_CORStaticMonth(int)
   AS RANGE left
   FOR VALUES (20120301)
   ```
3. Create Partition Scheme

   ```
   CREATE PARTITION SCHEME Partition_Scheme_CORStaticMonth
   AS PARTITION Partition_Range_CORStaticMonth
   TO (FFF_Fact_vvv_201203)
   ```
4. Add Files to the File Groups

   ```
   ALTER DATABASE [database] 
   ADD FILE( 
           NAME = N'FFF_Fact_vvv_201203', 
           FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\FFF_Fact_vvv_201203.ndf' , 
           SIZE = 2048KB , 
           FILEGROWTH = 1024KB 
           ) 
   TO FILEGROUP [FFF_Fact_vvv_201203]
   ```
5. Build Table with Partition Scheme applied

   ```
   IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[partition_Table]') AND type in (N'U'))
   DROP TABLE [dbo].[partition_Table]
   GO

   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[partition_Table]
   (
       CORStaticDateId         int
   ) ON  Partition_Scheme_CORStaticMonth ([CORStaticDateId])
   ```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as `int`s rather than, hmm, say `date`s?

Comment: it's a fact table that feeds into our SSAS cube. The true date exists in the date dimension

Comment: perfect approach to store dates as integers on a DW

Comment: I was lucky enough to inherit that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a partition scheme to apply to a table.

The order is:

1) Create your Filegroups

2) Create your partition Function

3) Attach Partition Scheme to FileGroups (using the partition Function)

4) Create table on partition Scheme

Check this [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/25/sql-server-2005-database-table-partitioning-tutorial-how-to-horizontal-partition-database-table/) for a tutorial

Comment: worked Great, Steps are easy: I'll post my code with the answer

Answer (score 0):

Is this just a naming issue, shouldn't:

```
) ON  CORStaticDateMonthPartition ([CORStaticDateId])
```

be

```
) ON  StaticDateMonthPartition ([CORStaticDateId])
```