# SSAS partition slice based on calculated dimension member

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, partitioning

I have an SSAS cube where data is partitioned by current year, last year, and prior to last year.  I'd like to set the partition slice property on the partitions, but I'm having trouble getting it to process correctly.

After looking at [SSAS Partition Slice Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657267/ssas-partition-slice-expression), I defined a calculated member `[Date].[Year].[All].[CurrentYear]`, and used that as my slice expression.  It's defined as:

```
StrToMember("[Date].[Year].&[" + Format(now(), "yyyy") + "]")
```

When I process the cube, it fails with an error, "The restrictions imposed on the partition slice were violated."  I've checked that the query that builds the slice is correct, and it works when I use a slice expression of `[Date].[Year].&[2019]`.

Is there something incorrect I'm doing here, or is what I'm trying to do impossible?

Comment: Check if member with the key 2019 exists in the Date dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSAS partition slice expression is quite restrictive. You cannot use dynamic MDX functions; moreover, you cannot specify infinite ranges like `{NULL:[Date].[Calendar].[Dec, 2008]}`. 
You have to specify slice expression explicitly, enumerating all its members if needed.
[MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/set-the-partition-slice-property-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017) is not complete, unfortunately. I would check whether do you really need a slice; SSAS itself does a pretty good job autodetecting slices on processing.
Another possible approach - define **static dimension member** on mentioned hierarchy, and use it in partition slice expression. Using the same hierarchy is important.

Comment: I was hoping there was some way around the dynamic MDX restriction, but it seems there isn't one.  I'll wait another day or two to see if there are any more answers, and if not, I'll accept yours.

Comment: @JulianGoldsmith, added another possible approach - use static dimension members, defined on the same hierarchy.

Comment: @Ferdipux by "static dimension members" are you saying to add a new column into the underlying sql dimension table?

Comment: @JulianGoldsmith, I meant creating a static set in Cube calculations, and assigning it to partition slice. Not sure about such setup, but I would give it a try.

Comment: @Ferdipux, I gave the static sets a try, but I unfortunately got the same error as with a calculated member.  Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know about those.